# Creating lots of sprites dynamically in libgdx

Tags: sprites, box2d, libgdx

I´m creating Groups that contains Sprites and adding bodies with box2D, but when I create many of this my animation gets very slow. How can I handle it?

Comment: You have to provide more specific information about what you are doing. Also, what does "my animation gets very slow" mean?

Comment: I'm creating many Sprites and I add them to my stage, over 100, and the frame rate  gets low (the slow animation) any clue ?

Comment: Can you show the code for how you create, store, and update the sprites?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this if you're using spritebatch http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SpriteBatch#Performance_tuning

And also if your bodies are static terrain and don't animate, then you should be using SpriteCache. Ex. you are building tile based terrain